# Getting Connection refused in a FTP client socket program

Tags: perl, sockets, ftp

I have this Perl script where I want to get the listing of the FTP server.

My understanding is that the FTP server opens a new connection back to the
clients host on some random port for sending data. Should I somehow create
a new socket and read from it? I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use 5.30.0;
use IO::Socket;

my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new("core9:21"); 

$socket->send("USER user7\r\n", 0);
$socket->send("PASS s$cret\r\n", 0);
#$socket->send("SYST\r\n", 0);
#$socket->send("HELP\r\n", 0);
#$socket->send("TYPE A\r\n", 0);
$socket->send("PORT 192,168,0,20,200,95\r\n", 0);
$socket->send("LIST\r\n", 0);
$socket->send("QUIT\r\n", 0);

while (my $line = <$socket>) {
    print($line); 
}

$socket->close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `PORT` command, which tells the FTP server to make a new connection to an IP:Port that *you* specify.  So yes, of course you have to actually create your own 2nd listening socket on that IP:Port before the server can connect to it.

Otherwise, use the `PASV` command instead (which you should anyway, since it is more friendly for clients who are running behind NAT routers), which tells the FTP server to open a listening port on its side which you can then connect a 2nd socket to.  The FTP server will tell you the IP:Port where you need to connect to.

Also, your code is not even remotely close to being a valid FTP client, since you are not reading or even looking at the server's responses to know if your commands are successful or failing.  You are not even reading the server's initial greeting to know if you are even allowed to send commands to it.

I STRONGLY suggest you read the official FTP protocol spec, [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959).

Comment: What do you mean by not looking? I get the server output on the console.

Comment: Your code is sending ALL of the commands to the server unconditionally AND THEN just dumping everything received on the socket to the console until the connection is closed. Your code is not parsing the responses in ANY way. This is NOT the way to handle FTP.

Comment: You MUST connect, then READ+PARSE THE GREETING, then send `USER` and READ+PARSE ITS REPLY, then send `PASS` and READ+PARSE  ITS REPLY only if `USER` asks for `PASS`, etc, until you get to `LIST`. Send `LIST` and READ+PARSE  ITS REPLY, then ESTABLISH THE 2ND CONNECTION and read the listing from THAT socket until finished, then close the 2nd socket and READ+PARSE ITS FINAL REPLY on the 1st socket. Then send `QUIT` and READ+PARSE ITS REPLY before closing the 1st socket.

Comment: [Read the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959), this is all covered in detail.

Comment: OK, I am starting to get it. I am going to read the document.